# How safe is it to read uploaded text in Flask using wtf

Tags: flask

I have a flask app and I want it so that the user can upload a text file which instead of being saved will be directly converted into a simple array assigned to a variable. Ideally I'll take the uploaded .txt file, check if it's in the proper format of an array that I can store in a variable, and if not give back an error. I'd like to prevent my VPS from being injected with a virus or other malicious code.

If I follow the instruction here (http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html) will this be sufficient to do what I want without being injected with a virus?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your VPS could be injected with malicious code, because by definition malicious code need to be executed.

If you just want to store the file you won't have any issue. Even if the text file is heartbleed all over again you will just store the code (or the binary for that matter) of the program, python won't try to execute it by itself.

So no, you won't be injected with a virus if you don't try to execute all the file you get posted.